# Browser saves cookie in wrong textbox

Tags: asp.net, html, browser, passwords

How can I force Browser saves the login cookie?
What I want is when user Logs in, browser ask him: "Do you want IE to remember the password for...? Y/N"
(Not the cookie to remember and do login automatically, that i already have implemented)

Another problem is, in my registration page, browser always save the field(textbox) of confirmation email --'

Answer (score 1):

> How can I force Browser saves the login cookie?

You can't. You can offer a cookie. The browser may or may not be configured to accept it.

> What I want is when user Logs in, browser ask him: "Do you want IE to remember the password for...? Y/N"

That isn't a cookie. That is form auto complete. Use obvious, English names for your `<input>` elements so that browsers are more likely to recognise them as credential fields (`name="username"` and `name="password"` for example).

Answer (score 0):

This is all down to the browser itself and not your code.

Browsers have the ability to save your login details and recognise when you come back to the site and pre-fill the details.

Similar for other inputs, they are automatically recognised by the browser and filled in.

Check your browser settings for these.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, it should work automatically if you have an input type="password" field.